# Passing object from one view to another controller to render a second view with that objects data

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a view that shows a list of items from the model. Each item has an image on it which is a clickable link. This link points to a RouteURL method which brings it to a new controller for the next view to be rendered with this items information.

The problem is I need to pass the items information to the controller that the RouteURL is invoking. There is 6 properties being passed so I didn't want to add them to the query string individually. Is there a better way to pass a single object to the next controller rather than passing the properties individually like that?

**Edit from comment responses.** 
For simplicity sake at this point, is there a way to post this object in a form without specifying each individual prop? For example:

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm("NewAction", "SameController", FormMethod.Post))
            {
              @Html.Hidden("NewObject.item.Id",Item.Id)
            }
```

This does work as I need it to, but I fear that if the object changes on the first controller, this will break since its not strongly typed. Is there a more strongly typed way to accomplish this?

Comment: Is there a data source? If so could you not just pass the Id of the item in and pull the rest of the data back from the data source?

Comment: There is an ID but I didn't want to query the DB again when the data is already on the previous page.

Comment: I can see why you'd want to do that but the better option is to pull that information back from the database so that way you don't have an issue with data inconsistency for example. Data sources are designed to be very quick so I wouldn't worry about the extra DB query. The only way I can think of would  be to store the list in either a cache like redis or memory but that would have a huge negative impact if there is a large volume of requests as that list would be stored in memory per request.

Comment: You cant pass the Object around like that,

Comment: Totally agree with @DavidFord. The web is (and should be) stateless. Instead of trying to pass mountains of data back and forth between requests, trying to shoe-horn state onto a stateless protocol, just pull the data fresh from the database.

Comment: You *could* do something like this if you altered things to work more like a form post as opposed to just a link.  But, I also agree with @DavidFord that it is better to just pass the ID and do the db hop.  Put a stopwatch in the code and you'll see that the db hop likely takes less than 100ms (probably less than 10ms) and thus is negligible.

Comment: I should clarify that this is hitting a webservice to get the data(which it has to do). The web service returns a days worth of data, then I have to dwindle it down to the single ID. That is my main concern with the approach of re-querying the data as its not a simple DB call. I will try it though to see how it works as I do agree with @DavidFord as well

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense.  But that still means that every time anyone hits the first page you have to make that api call?  If I were you I'd think of setting up a second db with that info in it because it sounds like that api is terribly inefficient.  But, in the mean time, I'd refactor the page to use form posts instead.

Comment: @mameesh That changes things, I'd personally looking into either having a backend service which will poll the web source frequently to detect changes and write it to a database of your own which you can query against much quicker. It may become out of sync for a short periods of time but you can change how long data may be stale for. Another option is to cache the results in something like redis and check the cache before making the request to the web source again. Doing either one of those options will cut out the waiting time for each single request.

Comment: You can use ajax call for it and bind full object through ajax on image click